# MVC Routing overload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to intercept a webapi call but only for a certain controller and am struggling.

I already have a route set up for default management like so:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and in the same webApiConfig i am assigning a custom handler so I can perform some internal authorisation with the following:

```
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomAuthorizationHandler());
```

I now need to be able to send a qebApiRequest through that has the same format as my default but I need to be handled differently for this single controller. Controller is responsible for the resetting of user passwords but my CustomAuthorizationHandler performs logic I want to skip so I though I would create a new PassThruHandler inheriting from `DelegateHandler` and then create a new route purely for this controller like so:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "PasswordResetApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { },
            constraints: new { controller = @"PasswordReset)" },
            handler: new PassThruHandler()
            );
```

but whenever I send my PasswordReset/1234 i still enter the `CustomAuthorizationHandler` is this not "doable"?

Answer (score 0):

How about applying your custom handler to all controllers except PasswordReset instead of adding it globally to `config.MessageHandlers`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: @"^PasswordReset",
    handler: new CustomAuthorizationHandler()
);
```

I have used a constraint to limit this routes to all controllers except `PasswordReset` for which you could create another route.